# Custom Container using UIScrollView with two fingers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I'm creating a container view controller where the child view controllers are shown like a paged scrollView. In this container controller I want to change between pages scrolling horizontally using two fingers. So I used a UIScrollView and I have set it like that:

```
self.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;  
self.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;  
self.scrollView.delegate = self;

[self.scrollView setContentOffset:[self rectForPage:1].origin];

for (UIGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer in self.scrollView.gestureRecognizers) {
    if ([gestureRecognizer  isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGR = (UIPanGestureRecognizer *) gestureRecognizer;
        panGR.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2;
    }
}
```

I also have implemented the `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender` method to avoid the vertical scrolling

```
 - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
     CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
     int page = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x +pageWidth/2) / pageWidth);
     self.pageControl.currentPage = page;
     [self.scrollView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x, 0)];
 }
```

Now the problem is that the childViewControllers subviews can't receive the touches from the user. I want the single touch to be passed throw the view hierarchy. I have read about subclassing UIScrollView to overwrite the method `- (BOOL)touchesShouldBegin:(NSSet *)touches  withEvent:(UIEvent *)event inContentView:(UIView *)view` but it's only called if the subviews are UIControl. How I can do it?

The purpose is that this ChildViewControllers have UIButtons inside and ScrollViews that should be used with singleTouches

Answer (score 0):

maybe not exactly, but this might help you. Create a scroll view subclass and implement this;

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // UIView will be "transparent" for touch events if we return NO
    for (id subview in self.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[YourViewController class]]) {
            YourViewController *VC = (YourViewController*) subview;

            if (CGRectContainsPoint(YourViewController.frame, point)) {
                return YES;
            }
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks fore the answer but it didn't. Work... Even if I return allways yes the buttons are not reactive in the child view controller view :(